# Generate Scripts equivalent for Transact SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

In SQL Server Management Studio, there is an option to 'Generate Scripts'.  The way we currently transfer a 2008 sql server database to a 2005 sql server database is by generating the scripts and running SQLCMD on that sql script file to push to a local instance of 2005 sql server.  I'm creating a C# program to do whole bunch of other tasks as well but I also need it to convert the 2008 database and move it to a 2005 sql server.  Is there a Transact sql statement or an easier way to convert the 2008 database to a 2005 database?  Thanks.

Comment: the question why springs to mind...

Comment: Its for our legacy system support.

Comment: And why are you developing on 2008 if you are supporting 2005, that way lies madness. Sooner or later you are going to use some code that 2005 won't recognize and finding out when you move to prod is a pretty bad time. It is very dangerous to develop on a newer version than production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your development deliverable should not be a database binary (the .MDF file), but a deployment script. You treat your database deployment and upgrade just like any other source file, place it under  source control, have peer code reviews at check in etc etc. Modifying directly the .MDF and then reverse engineering to deploy it is just plain bad. The problem you encountered now is just one of the problems, and there are many more problems, specially around the issue schema changes done during an application version upgrade. See [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/).

Now is true that the entire VS tool set is trying to guide you down the path of 'just edit your MDF in the VS Database Explorer and everything will be fine'. Nothing will be fine and one or more deployment meltdowns are just ahead in your life, but lets pretend that VS does a good thing.

You can automate the extraction of the current schema and deployment of it via 3rd party commercial tools like Red Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/), or you can roll your own 'Generate Scripts' fairly easy. SSMS all it does it invokes the SMO scripting capabilities to script out an entire database. You can do the same: instantiate a [`Scripter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) object instance, then add to it the objects you want scripted, then extract the T-SQL generated script. That is *exactly* what 'Generate Scripts' in SSMS does. There is an example in MSDN for [scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx):

```
   //Connect to the local, default instance of SQL Server. 
  Server srv = new Server(); 

   //Reference the AdventureWorks2008R2 database.  
  Database db = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks2008R2"]; 

   //Define a Scripter object and set the required scripting options. 
  Scripter scrp = new Scripter(srv); 
   scrp.Options.ScriptDrops = false; 
   scrp.Options.WithDependencies = true; 

   //Iterate through the tables in database and script each one. Display the script. 
   //Note that the StringCollection type needs the System.Collections.Specialized namespace to be included. 
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Urn[] smoObjects = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Urn[1] ;
   foreach (Table tb in db.Tables) {   
      smoObjects[0] = tb.Urn; 
      if (tb.IsSystemObject == false) { 
         System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection sc;
         sc = scrp.Script(smoObjects); 
         foreach ( string st in sc) { 
            Console.WriteLine(st); 
         } 
      } 
   }
```

Comment: Remus, thanks for your reply.  Your reply got me doing some more searching about classes that I was previously unaware of.  I came across the Transfer class which does exactly what I want it to do (With it, I dont have to write a sql script and call SQLCMD!) but it doesn't do one thing that I need it to do:  It doesn't copy all the constraints over (just the data).  So all the FKs, PKs and IXs are missing.  Do you know how I would transfer those too? I can't find the option to enable those to transfer as well?  Thanks!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b5219a28-64c2-462b-a263-66ae9cc9c45c/  This helped too.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Import from one DB in the other

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Goto 2005 Server Management Studio Console, Right Click in your Db and select Task>Import Data. Import data from SQL 2008 Server and follow the wizard. Save the package. Thats your code. Running too for populate

Comment: THe 2005 sql server is an Express version and the 2008 sql server is the full version but I cannot save the package.  I even did 2008 -> 2008 and still cannot save the package.

Comment: mmm You have all objects in SQL2005. Make export the SQL 2008 data with bcp utility . List your tables, and create a bat for genarte  fmt file and data dump. And import in sql 2005 in the same way

Answer (score 0):

Scripting the database objects out and then running them on the older instance is the way to go. If you have SQL 2008-specific features coded, you'll find it right off when you run the script on 2005 (so test before you try it on Production!).

Setting Compatibility Mode will **not** help here. If I have a (2008) declared table type and I use it with stored procedure parameters, there's *nothing* SQL or anyone else can do to migrate it to 2005. Using "modern" systems to support legacy systems is ugly at best.

Just 'cause I'm doing it again, my preferred migration path is:

- Have development, "staging", and production environments, all at 2005
- Upgrade staging to 2008
- Continue developing on dev/2005, and push changes to staging (2008) and production (2005). When it works on 2008 (and it almost certainly will), mgmt will be content with upgrading production. And your 2005 builds will still work on 2005 production.
- Upgrade production. Hey, it worked on staging, so it's safe and sane
- And everything generated from (2005) development works on (2008) staging and production
- And only then do you upgrade development and get to play with your new toys

Comment: That's similar to what we do.  Everything started with 2005.  Then development went to 2008 and production stayed at 2005.  Once our database was refined enough and ready, the production goes to 2008.  The problem is that we have to support legacy systems which would have 2005 on it so we can't break those.  I do the generate scripts all the time for every production release and it works great.  The thing is I am writing this automated program so there can be no management studio interaction so that anyone can run this and get a 2005 bak file from the 2008 server.